# How to stop npm script running in background automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, background, npm

Im using npm scripts, I have some of them that should run in parallel. I've got something like this:

```
...
scripts: {
   "a": "taskA &",
   "preb": "npm run a",
   "b": "taskB"
}
...
```

This is fine! But I'd like to kill automatically taskA running the background after taskB has finished.

How can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't believe npm is the best tool to manage complex relationships between processes.

You would be far better served by creating a node script that uses node's [`child_process`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module to manage the launching and killing of co-processes, perhaps using [`spawn`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).

Having said that, and in the spirit of always trying to provide a direct, usable answer..

You could structure your npm scripts like (*assumes* bash shell):

```
scripts:{
    runBoth: "npm runA & npm runB",     // run tasks A and B in parallel
    runA:    "taskA & TASKA_PID=$!",    // run task A and capture its PID into $TASKA_PID
    runB:    "taskB && kill $TASKA_PID" // run task B and if it completes successfully, kill task A using its saved PID
}
```

The only '*magic*' here is that:

1. when you run a command in the background using the `bash` shell (which is what happens when you add `&` to the end), you can discover it PID using `$!`, but only immediately after the command is run. (See [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Chapter 9. Another Look at  Variables - 9.1. Internal Variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PIDVARREF) for its description.)
2. taskB **must** call process.exit(0) on success or process.exit(-1) on failure so that the `&&` test is handled correctly. (See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100704/difference-between-executing-multiple-commands-with-and#122759) for more information.)

Comment: Thank you for that Bash trick! it is awesome. Your answer is the one I was looking for.

Comment: I don't think runB has access to $TASK_PID from runA.

Comment: @prongs - ok, what opsys? what version of node? Hard to help if I don't know about your setup. ;)

Comment: mac, and everything latest. Basically the variable isn't set, hence kill doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

The `npm-run-all` package may be what you're looking for:

```
$ npm install --save npm-run-all
```

Then in your `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "runA": "taskA",
    "runB": "taskB",
    "runBoth": "npm-run-all -p runA runB"
}
```

(`-p` runs them in parallel, use `-s` for sequential.)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. And if you add the ampersand at the end it runs even that script in the background. (eg: `"npm-run-all -p runA runB &"`) Works great. -- Just be sure to use `killall node` when you're done. :D

Answer (score 2):

Using the [concurrently package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) looks like a less tricky & painful way. This avoids detached processes (`&`) alltogether. And promises to be more cross-plattform, too.

```
npm install concurrently --save
```

and then in *package.json*

```
"runBoth": "concurrently \"npm run taskA\" \"npm run taskB\"",
```

Tested (under Ubuntu 16.04, npm 5.6), also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49725707/444255).