# Stop all processes depending on npm start…

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I am starting multiple npm tasks in parallel (using `&`, not just in sequence `&&`). Thus in **package.json**:

```
"start": "npm run watch-blog & npm run watch-data & npm run server",
```

And those sub-tasks are useful stuff to me like:

```
"watch-blog" : "watchy -w _posts/**/* -- touch _pages/blog.md",
```

### **Question:** How can I all shut down all three tasks together?

I noticed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>–<kbd>C</kbd> is only killing the last. (my 
watch-blog survives and keeps „touching“)

Closing the terminal window doesn't help. Only `killall node` does the job, but that's killing more than I would like to…

Comment: This seems like a potentially useful answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27809215/5699669

Answer (score 1):

Killing detached processes (that's the word…) will be a pain. One will have to look at pids, and more stuff coming your way. Not to mention cross-platform issues, if meant to work under windows...

**Easier and working:**

```
npm install concurrently --save
```

and thus

```
"start": "concurrently \"npm run watch-blog\" \"npm run watch-data\" \"npm run serve\"",
```

Tested (under Ubuntu 16.04, npm 5.6).